# How to get the next 12 future dates

Tags: mysql, date

I have a bit of code that tells you when a contact would not have been contacted and highlights that day on a calender. i.e. If you last contacted the person yesterday, then a highlighted day will appear one month from that on next months page.

What I would like to do is do that for every month up to a year. So in the previous example, if I moved one month beyond the highlighted day, it would be 'not contacted for two months', three months, four months and so fourth up to 12 months.

Here is what I'm using now for the 'not contacted for one month' query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE(DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), '%Y-%c-%d') AS overDate
    FROM contact_method_history
WHERE DATE(DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) = '$SQLDate'
AND entityRef = ".$this->entityId."
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

$this->entityId could be something like 153 or 9045, its just a reference to the contact.

$SQLDate is in the form of '2012-05-09'.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't complete my title properly. It should read 'how to get the next 12 future dates'.

Comment: Whilst this *can* be done in SQL, I'd suggest it probably belongs in your application code.

Comment: You can edit the question - and the title.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps a for loop with INTERVAL $i MONTH, where $i goes from 1 to 12, do you think that is the most efficient way?

Comment: Agree with @eggyal. Not only trivial in application code, less data to pull from the server.

Comment: I don't get it: according to your query, the column [overDate] will always have the same value: $SQLDate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't agree with comments: if you do a loop then you will run 12 queries instead of 1, which is decreasing performances. In the other hand, the statement for a "all in one" query is not trivial:

```
SELECT date
, i.m
, DATE_FORMAT(DATE(DATE_ADD(cmh.date, INTERVAL i.m MONTH)), '%Y-%c-%d') AS overDate
FROM contact_method_history AS cmh
, (
    SELECT 1 as m
    UNION ALL SELECT 2 as m
    UNION ALL SELECT 3 as m
    UNION ALL SELECT 4 as m
    UNION ALL SELECT 5 as m
    UNION ALL SELECT 6 as m
    UNION ALL SELECT 7 as m
    UNION ALL SELECT 8 as m
    UNION ALL SELECT 9 as m
    UNION ALL SELECT 10 as m
    UNION ALL SELECT 11 as m
    UNION ALL SELECT 12 as m
) AS i
WHERE ( DATE(DATE_ADD(cmh.date, INTERVAL i.m MONTH)) = '$SQLDate' )
AND (entityRef = ".$this->entityId.")
GROUP BY i.m, DATE(DATE_ADD(cmh.date, INTERVAL i.m MONTH))
```

Comment: I can't speak for anyone else, but I wasn't proposing making any more than 1 query: simply, having obtained the last contact date, then highlight the monthly anniversaries in the application - no further queries are required.

Comment: I understand what you mean now. That is the best idea so far, simply using the last contacted date as reference and calculating the dates for the next however many months.